# Are there any cheap solutions to deal with Sickened condition?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, conditions

Are there any mundane items that deal with sickened condition?

Comment: A_S00's answer is great, I just want to also add that if this is a one-time need, the potion equivalent might be available as well as the wands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### No, there are no mundane items that remove the Sickened condition.

You might expect there to be "medicinal herbs" or something that would do this, but as far as I can tell with some searching, nothing like that exists in the rules.

---

If you're willing to step outside the realm of "mundane items," you have a few options, but most of them require at least some amount of investment of character resources, not just a handful of gold pieces:

- **Being naturally immune:**  Warforged are naturally immune to the sickened condition.
- **Strong Stomach** (feat, Dungeonscape p. 64):  This feat, which requires Con 13 and Endurance, makes you immune to the sickened condition.
- The **Panacea** spell (SpC p. 152):  Cleric 4/Druid 5 spell that removes a variety of conditions, including Sickened.
- The **Healing Lorecall** spell (SpC p. 110):  Cleric 2/Druid 2/Ranger 1 spell that allows the caster to remove conditions, including Sickened, with subsequent curing spells, as long as they have enough ranks in the Heal skill.
- The **Resurgence** spell (SpC p. 174):  Cleric 1/Paladin 1/Blackguard 1 spell that grants a new saving throw to someone to avoid an effect they're already suffering.  This can remove Sickened if the original effect allowed a saving throw (which many do).
- The **[Heal](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/heal.htm)** spell:  Removes a whole lot of things, including Sickened.  Very high level, though.

The spell options from the above list, of course, can be made into [wands](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wands.htm), so if you or a party member have the relevant spell(s) on your class list, or a few ranks in [Use Magic Device](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/useMagicDevice.htm), that's a way to get access to them without much of an investment of character resources, just a bit of gold.  A wand of Resurgence, in particular, is a great thing for someone in the party to have.

In addition, a [widely-suggested house rule](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?246531-Making-the-Heal-skill-relevant) is to allow the [Heal](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/heal.htm) skill to remove conditions like Sickened and Nauseated, to help deal with the fact that the skill is normally [really bad](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/96843/30299).

---

Finally, let me suggest my personal favorite method of dealing with the Sickened condition, which requires *zero* investment of gold *or* character resources:  **ignoring it completely.**

At the end of the day, all that [Sickened](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/conditionSummary.htm#sickened) actually does is give you -2 on a few checks.  This *does* include saving throws, which is pretty bad, so you'd definitely rather have it not happen to you, but it's not like [Nauseated](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/conditionSummary.htm#nauseated), [Staggered](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/conditionSummary.htm#staggered), or [Panicked](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/conditionSummary.htm#panicked), where it actually *prevents you from taking actions*.  Usually, even if you *do* have the ability to do so, it's not worth spending an action to remove the Sickened condition.  The best way to deal with being Sickened is often to let out a big sigh, and then take the same action you were going to take anyway, but with a -2 penalty.